# DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body embed.image.url: Scheme "[object response]" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https')

Tags: javascript, api, discord, discord.js, chart.js

So I am trying to fetch a .png file from quickchart.io with the following code:

```js
 async exec(message, args) {

        console.log(chalk.green("chart requested  " + chalk.yellow(message.author.username) + " in " + chalk.magentaBright(message.channel.guild.name)));
        console.log(args.coin)
        const getChart = async () => {

            const result = await fetch(`https://quickchart.io/chart?chart={
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                  labels: ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'],
                  datasets: [{
                    label: 'Revenue',
                    data: [100, 200, 300, 400],fill:false
                  }]
                }
              }&backgroundColor=transparent&width=500&height=300&devicePixelRatio=1.0&format=png&version=2.9.3`)
            const json = await result
            return json
        }
        let com = await getChart()
        if (message) {
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setImage(`${com}`)

            message.channel.send({ embed }).catch(function (rej) {
                message.channel.send("Sorry, I was unable to process this command. Make sure that I have full send permissions for embeds and messages and then try again!");
                console.log(chalk.red('Error sending trending list! : ' + chalk.cyan(rej)));
            });
        }

    }
```

I know I am making a huge mistake, but I wanna understand more about this error and what I am doing wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide an image url so instead of your current fetch where you try to get the image you have to provide the quickchart link like so:

```js
let com = `https://quickchart.io/chart?chart={
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                  labels: ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'],
                  datasets: [{
                    label: 'Revenue',
                    data: [100, 200, 300, 400],fill:false
                  }]
                }
              }&backgroundColor=transparent&width=500&height=300&devicePixelRatio=1.0&format=png&version=2.9.3`

if (message) {
  // rest of code
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks it works, but I also worked a way around it, I used the npm package quickchart-js instead, much more convenient!